# Cannot invoke css() or xpath() on scrapy.Response

Tags: python, scrapy

I tried to write a web crawler with `scrapy`. However, when I tried to use its interactive shell to test [one of the page](http://www.momoshop.com.tw/goods/GoodsDetail.jsp?i_code=2153613&str_category_code=1714900050&cid=ec&oid=3e&mdiv=1000000000-bt_0_209_01-bt_0_209_01_e57&ctype=B).

The error message,

```
2016-03-01 22:15:08 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: momo)
2016-03-01 22:15:08 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-03-01 22:15:08 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'momo.spiders', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['momo.spiders'], 'FEED_URI': 'j.json', 'BOT_NAME': 'momo'}
2016-03-01 22:15:08 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-03-01 22:15:08 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-03-01 22:15:08 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-03-01 22:15:08 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-03-01 22:15:08 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-03-01 22:15:08 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-03-01 22:15:08 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-03-01 22:15:09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.momoshop.com.tw/main/Main.jsp> (referer: None)
2016-03-01 22:15:11 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.momoshop.com.tw/goods/GoodsDetail.jsp?i_code=1697199&str_category_code=2200700058&cid=ec&oid=1c&mdiv=1000000000-bt_0_209_01-bt_0_209_01_e11&ctype=B> (referer: http://www.momoshop.com.tw/main/Main.jsp)
2016-03-01 22:15:11 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.momoshop.com.tw/goods/GoodsDetail.jsp?i_code=3753480&str_category_code=1514200303&cid=ec&oid=2a&mdiv=1000000000-bt_0_209_01-bt_0_209_01_e25&ctype=B> (referer: http://www.momoshop.com.tw/main/Main.jsp)
2016-03-01 22:15:11 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.momoshop.com.tw/goods/GoodsDetail.jsp?i_code=3754704&str_category_code=1417802005&cid=ec&oid=1f&mdiv=1000000000-bt_0_209_01-bt_0_209_01_e20&ctype=B> (referer: http://www.momoshop.com.tw/main/Main.jsp)
2016-03-01 22:15:11 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.momoshop.com.tw/goods/GoodsDetail.jsp?i_code=3811447&str_category_code=1318900078&cid=ec&oid=1d&mdiv=1000000000-bt_0_209_01-bt_0_209_01_e14&ctype=B> (referer: http://www.momoshop.com.tw/main/Main.jsp)
{'Date': ['Tue, 01 Mar 2016 14:15:10 GMT'], 'Set-Cookie': ['loginRsult=null;Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-01970 00:00:10 GMT;Path=/', 'loginUser=null;Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-01970 00:00:10 GMT;Path=/', 'cardUser=null;Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-01970 00:00:10 GMT;Path=/', '18YEARAGREE=null;Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-01970 00:00:10 GMT;Path=/', 'Browsehist=1697199,3753480,3754704,2189725;Path=/', 'FTOOTH=22;Path=/', 'DCODE=2200700058;Path=/'], 'Content-Type': ['']}
2016-03-01 22:15:11 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.momoshop.com.tw/goods/GoodsDetail.jsp?i_code=1697199&str_category_code=2200700058&cid=ec&oid=1c&mdiv=1000000000-bt_0_209_01-bt_0_209_01_e11&ctype=B> (referer: http://www.momoshop.com.tw/main/Main.jsp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Shane/Desktop/scrapy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/Users/Shane/Desktop/scrapy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 28, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/Users/Shane/Desktop/scrapy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/Users/Shane/Desktop/scrapy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Users/Shane/Desktop/scrapy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Users/Shane/Desktop/scrapy/momo/momo/spiders/default_spider.py", line 35, in parseGoods
    item.item = response.css('h1').extract()
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'css'
```

---

#### Updates

I found that this particular page does not has `Content-Type` on its response, it's written on its `head/meta`.

#### Code

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.http import Request

class MomoItem(scrapy.Item):
    item  = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    specification = scrapy.Field()

class MomoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "momo"
    allowed_domains = ["www.momoshop.com.tw"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.momoshop.com.tw/main/Main.jsp"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/goods")]/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parseGoods)

        # for href in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/category")]'):
        #     url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        #     yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
        #
        # for href in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/brand")]'):
        #     url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        #     yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)


    def parseGoods(self, response):
        item = MomoItem()
        print(response.headers)
        item.item = response.css('h1').extract()
        item.price = response.xpath('//ul[@class="prdPrice"]/li/span/text()').extract()
        print(item)

        yield item
```

---

#### Response to JeD's answer

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Shane/Desktop/scrapy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/Shane/Desktop/scrapy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 48, in process_spider_input
    return scrape_func(response, request, spider)
  File "/Users/Shane/Desktop/scrapy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 145, in call_spider
    dfd.addCallbacks(request.callback or spider.parse, request.errback)
  File "/Users/Shane/Desktop/scrapy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 299, in addCallbacks
    assert callable(callback)
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies at the default `scrapy` HTML Parser. Once I switched to another parser, it works like a charm. `lxml` doesn't seem to parse broken HTML as flawlessly as Beautiful Soup 4.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import scrapy

class MomoItem(scrapy.Item):
    item  = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    # specification = scrapy.Field()

class MomoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "momo"
    allowed_domains = ["www.momoshop.com.tw"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.momoshop.com.tw/main/Main.jsp"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/goods")]/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            self.parseGoods(response)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parseGoods)

        # for href in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/category")]'):
        #     url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        #     yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
        #
        # for href in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/brand")]'):
        #     url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        #     yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)


    def parseGoods(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response._body, 'html.parser')

        item = MomoItem()
        item['item'] = soup.find_all('h1')[0].get_text()
        item['price'] = soup.find_all('ul', class_='prdPrice')[0]
                            .find_all('li', class_='special')[0].span.get_text()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using

`from scrapy.selector import Selector`

in your bot? The code of the bot would be useful. Also these should be the only attributes the object has.
response.css() is just a convenience function.(http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

EDÍT:

Problem lies in the callback. Callback function needs arguments self.parseGoods(response) otherwise .css() is used on the function parseGoods. Worked on my laptop.

EDITEDIT:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for href in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/goods")]/@href'):

        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        self.parseGoods(response)
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parseGoods(response))

    # for href in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/category")]'):
    #     url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
    #     yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
    #
    # for href in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/brand")]'):
    #     url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
    #     yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)


def parseGoods(self, response):
    item = MomoItem()
    print(response.headers)
    item['item'] = response.css('h1').extract()
    item['price'] = response.xpath('//ul[@class="prdPrice"]/li/span/text()').extract()
    print(item)

    return item
```

Alright, this should work.
Changed yield item to return and changed the item calls e.g. item['item'] instead of item.item
Try it out and tell me if s.th. is wrong

Comment: You are right, those are the only attributes that should be there. But why can't I invoke `css()` or `xpath()`?

Comment: Does adding  'from scrapy.selector import Selector' after import scrapy in the bot work?

Comment: Try changing yield Request(url, callback=self.parseGoods) to
yield Request(url, callback=self.parseGoods(self,response))

Comment: can you share your code, i can't get this to work with `yield Request(url, callback=self.parseGoods(self,response))`. According to its [tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/intro/tutorial.html#following-links), mine seems correct.

Comment: Yeah, my fault v.v 
It is without self, but another error crops up, check edited answer

Comment: it now complains that the `callback` provided is not a callable.

Comment: That is weird :/ 
Works for me with output and everything.

And you could call it before... ö.ö
Did you change the name of the function?
Or maybe some weird indentation error?

Comment: Its what happens to me if you use yield instead of return in parseGoods

Maybe you forgot the last line?

Comment: If you do `callback=self.parseGoods(response)`, you're binding the callback to a value, and not the function as you've invoked it.